# Does playing with friends increase your ability to gain infernal rings faster?

Tags: diablo-iii

Assuming the probability of getting key is 25% (torment 1).

If playing single, we get:

- 4 tries per key
- 4 keys for machine
- 4 machines per organ
- 4 organs per ring

So a total of 256 attempts, for a single ring.

What about if we play with 4 of our friends? Does that increase our chances of getting those rings?

Comment: If only it was that simple... I usually have to do way more than 4 runs per key, and that was with 2 people in party. Also, keys are untradable, so I don't see how partying speeds it up.

Comment: @Chippies More dmg, faster kills. More people, more magic find.

Comment: @Assylum ah, I didn't think of it that way. More people don't necessarily make the kills faster though, because the HP scales up, but I see your point.

Comment: More people also increases the chance of finding keys and number of portals that can be opened.  If we go through and kill all the keywardens.  Lets say all of them drop a key for every party member.  With 1 player, that's 1 machine.  for 2 players, 2 machines. four players gives you four machines.  That means more portals in a game so more chance of getting an organ quicker.

Answer (score 3):

With 4 players you get the keys **a lot** faster.

- You need 1/4 as many runs because you get the same amount of keys and
  can share portals.
- You increase magic find.
- You can split to find the keywardens and port to eachother.
- You can kill the bosses on higher torment than on your own because of partybuffs+revive

Easiest way to do this is splitting up for act 1,2,4 at first then as soon as someone finds one you port to them until only act 3 is left and then everyone ports there and search the map.

Comment: I've never heard of a keywarden in act V? Is there really one, or is it a mistake?

Comment: Yes but by how much? My guess is it still take 64 play

Comment: 64 is a lot less than 256 though..